# "there was a prblem sending the command to the program" Error Message

Tags: ms-project

A  bit of a shot in the dark but I am having difficulties with MS Project 2010 opening a file.

Upon loading of the file that is located on a smb share I get this error message:

"There was a problem sending the command to the program"

Tried the following:

- rebooting
- repairing ms project 2010
- reinstalling ms project 2010
- tried opening it on another system - (got no error on one system but got the same error on another system)
- various registry hacks found on Google

I want to understand more about the error message.  I have been reading that this error message has to do with the DDE and it is probably a link within the project file that is causing the error message.  How do I pinpoint the problem within the Project File?

Answer (score 0):

Project files are particularly susceptible to corruption. Try to rebuild it by:

- open the file on a computer with no errors
- save it in XML format
- open the XML file and save it in mpp format

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Delete the registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MSProject.Project.9\shell\Open\ddeexec

found here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-project/msproject-2010-there-was-a-problem-sending-the/1f6bba31-4580-4844-9aa9-79ec04a35ea3?auth=1